# Error inflating class TextView on 4.4.2

Tags: android

`Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class TextView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SourceFile:70)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SourceFile:56)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(SourceFile:6487)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(SourceFile:5674)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5557)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5553)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(SourceFile:2229)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(SourceFile:556)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(SourceFile:1516)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:608)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:170)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(SourceFile:3693)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(SourceFile:3410)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:3962)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:610)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:443)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_notifications_white_12dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020064
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2101)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(SourceFile)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(SourceFile)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(SourceFile:103)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(SourceFile:1024)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(SourceFile:1081)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SourceFile:70)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SourceFile:56)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(SourceFile:6487)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(SourceFile:5674)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5557)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5553)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(SourceFile:2229)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(SourceFile:556)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(SourceFile:1516)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:608)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:170)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(SourceFile:3693)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(SourceFile:3410)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:3962)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:610)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:443)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2097)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(SourceFile)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.(SourceFile)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(SourceFile:103)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(SourceFile:1024)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(SourceFile:1081)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(SourceFile:70)
       at wscconnect.android.adapters.AppAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SourceFile:56)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(SourceFile:6487)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(SourceFile:5674)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5557)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(SourceFile:5553)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(SourceFile:2229)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(SourceFile:556)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(SourceFile:1516)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:608)
       at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(SourceFile:170)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(SourceFile:3693)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(SourceFile:3410)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:3962)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:610)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:443)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)`

Occurs in this line on Android 4.4.2 -  it works fine in several other versions:

```
View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_app, parent, false);
```

My layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_challenge_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f6f6f6">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_challenge_cover_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_logo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_unread_notifications"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_users"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_people_white_12dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_primary"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/card_challenge_cover_container"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_url"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/list_app_name"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="11sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which is line no `33`

Comment: post the complete error, not just a part of it.

Comment: yep, post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Updated with the whole stacktrace. Sry for the formatting. Editing on a phone is a pain.

Comment: you are using vector drawables on 5- devices? (pre-lollipop) - in your case 4.4.2 - you have to use support library for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawable vectors are generally working on pre lollipop devices, when using the support library.
Somehow they do not work in `drawableStart`, `drawableEnd` etc. attributes.

I replaced my

```
       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_app_users"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_people_white_12dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_primary"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
```

with a slightly more complex layout, which works on all devices:

```
            <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/list_app_users_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_primary">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_people_white_12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_app_users"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this file is not exist in your project res/drawable/ic_notifications_white_12dp.xml

so you have to remove this line

```
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_12dp"
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: 1- make sure its on drawable folder not mipmap, 2- make sure thats the file contains invalid code, cuz you have also this error "invalid drawable tag vector"

Answer (score -1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_app, parent, false);
```